# Financial Instrument vs Financial Product

Tags: trading

From this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_instrument): where explained the relationship between asset-classes and financial-instrument types

That's good, but [here](http://www.economywatch.com/investment/financial-products.html) -Types of financial products: shares, bonds

So is Financial Instrument = Financial Product ?

Comment: Strictly speaking bonds and shares are Financial Instruments. To describe them as Financial Products seems a bit careless or sloppy, but perhaps OK. In a job interview (or to impress my boss) I would use "Financial Instrument". But don't waste time on this, it is a minor issue.

Comment: The proper definition of Financial Product is that it is (believe it or not) just another name for a Financial Service, a service which a financial firm delivers to a Client. Examples are: a bank account, an insurance contract, a brokerage account. A Financial Instrument on the other hand gives the owner specific legal rights recognized by law (the rights of a shareholder, of a bondholder) and these rights are transferred when the ownership changes. Stocks, bonds, options can be transferred from one person to another through appropriate mechanisims. OTOH u dont sell ur bk acc'nt, you close it.

Comment: My comments have now been incorporated into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking bonds and shares are Financial Instruments. To describe them as Financial Products (as done in the web site you quoted) seems careless or sloppy use of language, but perhaps OK in everyday life. In a job interview (or to impress my boss) I would use "Financial Instrument". But don't waste time on this, it is a minor issue.

What is the distinction? The proper definition of Financial Product is that it is (believe it or not) just another name for a Financial Service, a service which a financial firm delivers to a Client. [Marketing personnel are fond of using the word "product" in this general sense]. Examples are: a bank account, an insurance contract, a brokerage account. A Financial Instrument on the other hand gives the owner specific legal rights recognized by law (the rights of a shareholder, of a bondholder) and these rights are transferred when the ownership changes. Stocks, bonds, options can be transferred from one person to another through appropriate mechanisms. OTOH you don't sell your bank account when you move and no longer need it, you close it, and maybe open another account with another bank (with different terms and conditions) in another city. It is a direct relationship between you and the bank, not an impersonal legal right that can be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

The instrument has a direct correlation with market information (Option, Future, CFD ...), whereas product is generally an account, Bonds, Shares and loan.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct because financial products can also be options.